# Confirmation message before removing a product from cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I just notice that in WooCommerce if customer removes a product from cart, there is no warning message or confirmation before deleting it.

Is there any ways to make a confirmation before removing a product from cart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [WC_Cart remove_cart_item()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_remove_cart_item) method [**source code here**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1010) you will see on line 1015 that you can only use **`woocommerce_remove_cart_item`** action hook that is triggered before an item is removed from cart.

As removing an item is ajax driven in cart page, to do what you are expecting is certainly possible, but something really complicated.

> Remember that on cart page, you already got a notice when you remove a cart items, that allow you to restore it… So adding a confirmation notice, is not really viable and even disturbing for customer experience.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much for your help. I just see that Woocommerce already has UNDO notice :)